# Produce Results From Multiple SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that has publishers and each month they submit a time sheet. To find the publishers who have submitted a report this month I run this query to show me all publisher reports submitted this month...

```
SELECT              c2.FullName AS ContactFullName, 
                    c2.LastName AS ContactLastName, 
                    c2.ContactId AS PublisherGUID, 
                    f2.jajw_groupname AS FSGName, 
                    b2.jajw_FieldServiceGroup AS FieldServiceGroupGUID, 
                    b2.jajw_reportId AS ReportGUID, 
                    b2.jajw_id AS ReportID,
                    b2.jajw_ReportMonthId AS ReportMonthGUID,
                    b2.jajw_ReportYearId AS ReportYearGUID,  
                    r2.jajw_name AS ReportMonthName, 
                    r2.jajw_CalendarDate AS ReportMonthCalDate, 
                    y2.jajw_name AS ReportYearName 

FROM                ContactBase AS c2 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_reportBase AS b2 ON c2.ContactId = b2.jajw_PublisherId 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_reportyearBase AS y2 ON b2.jajw_ReportYearId = y2.jajw_reportyearId 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_reportmonthBase AS r2 ON b2.jajw_ReportMonthId = r2.jajw_reportmonthId 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_fieldservicegroupBase AS f2 ON b2.jajw_FieldServiceGroup = f2.jajw_fieldservicegroupId
WHERE               c2.StateCode = '0' 
AND                 b2.jajw_ReportYearId = 'A507DFBF-B9CE-E611-A953-002248013EC3'
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840001 
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840005 
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840006
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840007
ORDER BY ContactLastName
```

The next step is to get a subset of the publishers who have not submitted a report, so the following query retrieves all publishers and then tells me which ones are NOT in the above query:

```
WITH 
ALLPUBLISHERSUNFILTERED AS
(
SELECT              c2.FullName AS ContactFullName, 
                    c2.LastName AS ContactLastName, 
                    c2.ContactId AS PublisherGUID 
FROM                ContactBase AS c2 
WHERE               c2.StateCode = '0' 
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840001 
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840005 
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840006
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840007
),

REPORTERS AS
(
SELECT              c2.FullName AS ContactFullName, 
                    c2.LastName AS ContactLastName, 
                    c2.ContactId AS PublisherGUID, 
                    f2.jajw_groupname AS FSGName, 
                    b2.jajw_FieldServiceGroup AS FieldServiceGroupGUID, 
                    b2.jajw_reportId AS ReportGUID, 
                    b2.jajw_id AS ReportID,
                    b2.jajw_ReportMonthId AS ReportMonthGUID,
                    b2.jajw_ReportYearId AS ReportYearGUID,  
                    r2.jajw_name AS ReportMonthName, 
                    r2.jajw_CalendarDate AS ReportMonthCalDate, 
                    y2.jajw_name AS ReportYearName 

FROM                ContactBase AS c2 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_reportBase AS b2 ON c2.ContactId = b2.jajw_PublisherId 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_reportyearBase AS y2 ON b2.jajw_ReportYearId = y2.jajw_reportyearId 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_reportmonthBase AS r2 ON b2.jajw_ReportMonthId = r2.jajw_reportmonthId 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_fieldservicegroupBase AS f2 ON b2.jajw_FieldServiceGroup = f2.jajw_fieldservicegroupId
WHERE               c2.StateCode = '0' 
AND                 b2.jajw_ReportYearId = 'A507DFBF-B9CE-E611-A953-002248013EC3'
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840001 
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840005 
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840006
AND                 c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment != 640840007
)

SELECT          a.ContactFullName, 
                a.ContactLastName, 
                a.PublisherGUID
       FROM     ALLPUBLISHERSUNFILTERED a
       WHERE    NOT EXISTS   (SELECT    *
                             FROM       REPORTERS rp
                             WHERE      a.PublisherGUID = rp.PublisherGUID)
```

The final step is the piece i am struggling with. I need to combine the two result sets together so that I get a list with the combined results.

Comment: *HELP!* is not a useful problem description or question. Have you made any effort to do this yourself before posting? If so, what specific problem did you run into that we can help solve? Do you have a **specific problem**, rather than a *please write this SQL for me* post? (And TSQL is a SQL-Server specific term, which cannot possibly involve MySQL. It's important to match your tags with what you're actually using rather than just randomly add those containing things that look similar. Tags have relevance here, and SQL dialects are very different in functionality and syntax.)

Comment: `WITH()` is not supported in MySQL.

Comment: And just union the the two with an indicator field to distinguished `SELECT` results.

Comment: @kenWhite Did you not read the very scentence before the word help then? "I need to combine the two result sets together so that I get a list with the combined results."

This is what I need to do. Apologies for using the incorrect tags and thank you for the clarification. If you don't want to help, please don't feel the need to reply.

Comment: @parfait Thanks, I used the incorrect tag so (they were ones suggested by the site when i posted) so sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the suggestion about Union. I tried this but i dont have all of the same fields in both data sets. However, all of the fields from DataSet 1 are in DataSet 2. How can i combine them with this?

Comment: @JoelAbbott - you still did not tag your RDMS. SQL is a language shared among various dialects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run a `UNION` query filling `NULL` in fields without applicable data. And consider adding an indicator field for submitted/not submitted such as *PublisherType*:

```
WITH 
ALLPUBLISHERSUNFILTERED AS
(
SELECT              'NOT SUBMITTED' AS PublisherType,
                    c2.FullName AS ContactFullName, 
                    c2.LastName AS ContactLastName, 
                    c2.ContactId AS PublisherGUID,
                    NULL AS FSGName, 
                    NULL AS FieldServiceGroupGUID, 
                    NULL AS ReportGUID, 
                    NULL AS ReportID,
                    NULL AS ReportMonthGUID,
                    NULL AS ReportYearGUID,  
                    NULL AS ReportMonthName, 
                    NULL AS ReportMonthCalDate, 
                    NULL AS ReportYearName  
FROM                ContactBase AS c2 
WHERE               c2.StateCode = '0' 
AND                 NOT c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment 
                    IN (640840001, 640840005, 640840006, 640840007)
),

REPORTERS AS
(
SELECT              'SUBMITTED' AS PublisherType,
                    c2.FullName AS ContactFullName, 
                    c2.LastName AS ContactLastName, 
                    c2.ContactId AS PublisherGUID, 
                    f2.jajw_groupname AS FSGName, 
                    b2.jajw_FieldServiceGroup AS FieldServiceGroupGUID, 
                    b2.jajw_reportId AS ReportGUID, 
                    b2.jajw_id AS ReportID,
                    b2.jajw_ReportMonthId AS ReportMonthGUID,
                    b2.jajw_ReportYearId AS ReportYearGUID,  
                    r2.jajw_name AS ReportMonthName, 
                    r2.jajw_CalendarDate AS ReportMonthCalDate, 
                    y2.jajw_name AS ReportYearName 

FROM                ContactBase AS c2 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_reportBase AS b2 ON c2.ContactId = b2.jajw_PublisherId 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_reportyearBase AS y2 ON b2.jajw_ReportYearId = y2.jajw_reportyearId 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_reportmonthBase AS r2 ON b2.jajw_ReportMonthId = r2.jajw_reportmonthId 
LEFT JOIN           jajw_fieldservicegroupBase AS f2 ON b2.jajw_FieldServiceGroup = f2.jajw_fieldservicegroupId
WHERE               c2.StateCode = '0' 
AND                 b2.jajw_ReportYearId = 'A507DFBF-B9CE-E611-A953-002248013EC3'
AND                 NOT c2.jajw_CongregationAssignment 
                    IN (640840001, 640840005, 640840006, 640840007)
)

SELECT   *
FROM     ALLPUBLISHERSUNFILTERED a
WHERE    NOT EXISTS  
         (SELECT     1
          FROM       REPORTERS rp
          WHERE      a.PublisherGUID = rp.PublisherGUID)

UNION ALL

SELECT   *
FROM     REPORTERS
```